# How to Pull info from another model within a DetailsView template (without ForeignKey)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to pull data from two models within a DetailsView template (in Django). There is of course a primary model (eg. Articles) associated with the view, which is easy to access. However, I want to access data from a model (eg. Terms). I do not want to use ForeignKey because I will be using many 'Terms' in each 'Article,' and since ForeignKey will allow me to link to only row in the Terms model, I will have to set-up mutiple ForeignKey fields, which can get messy fast.

I was thinking that this could be accomplished using get_context_data or templatetags, but haven't have had any luck yet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) you can add any queryset or context value you like to call  in your template context like `book_list` below will list all books and it doesn't has to be linked with any other models..

```
#views.py
class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context

#yourtemplate.html
{% for book in book_list %}
    {% if book %}
        {{ book.title }}
    {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
       No book_list found.
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, @misraX. This would help me get all the values from the Book model. How would I pass a parameter for a particular book from within the template? Say, I would to access book1 in one article, and book2 and book3 in another article.

May be I could use an if `__exact` command within the template? Not sure... even if that works, it would require querying all records within a model to access a single record, every time. What do you think?